# Copy Values of Multi Area Range to Another Sheet in a Performant Way

Tags: vba, excel

I have a named range (bufferFields) in Excel that looks like this:

`=Panel!$G$3:$G$24;Panel!$J$2:$J$20;Panel!$M$2:$M$14;Panel!$C$14;Panel!$M$15:$M$26`

What would be a performant way to put the values of all the 67 cells in this multi area range in another sheet (History), in the same sequence as they are defined in the range, so that I can keep a record of the state of the Panel sheet for each iteration of the calculations I make on my vba code?

For each run of my algorithm, I would like to record all bufferFields values to a different row on History.

This is what I did so far, and it works as expected, but I think the performance is suffering from the cycling through all the cells in the original range (instead of having a method or vba function to make it all in one go):

```
dim c as range, column as integer, row as integer

column = 1
row = 1 ' this is controlled in another portion of the sub


For Each c In Range("bufferFields").Cells
    Sheets("History").Cells(row, column) = c.Value
    column = column + 1
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the range into an array, then constructing a new array to write to the second sheet, will run about 30 times faster than going cell by cell, using random values in the cells.  In addition, you should turn off ScreenUpdating, Calculation and, if you are using Event Macros, disable them also.

When you read a multiple area range into an array, you have to do it area by area; and you also need to test to ensure the area being read in is one cell or multiple.  Here is some specimen code.  Note that I had to use History_ as the name of the worksheet as, in US-
English version of Excel, History is a reserved word.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyBufferFields()
    Dim I As Long
    Dim J As Long, K As Long, L As Long
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lRW As Long
   lRW = 1 'Row number to be set
With [bufferfields]
    ReDim vRes(1 To 1, 1 To .Count)
    For I = 1 To .Areas.Count
        vSrc = .Areas(I)
        If IsArray(vSrc) Then
        For J = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
            For K = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
                L = L + 1
                vRes(1, L) = vSrc(J, K)
            Next K
        Next J
        Else
            L = L + 1
            vRes(1, L) = vSrc
        End If
    Next I
End With
Worksheets("History_").Cells(lRW, 1).Resize(columnsize:=UBound(vRes, 2)) = vRes

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Ron. This reduced the time of this particular task by almost 75%.

Comment: @carlossierra I'm glad it worked out for you.  By the way, I am removing the Dim C line as it is superfluous.  I had it there when I was running the test timing the cell-by-cell method vs the VBA Array method, and neglected to delete it.

Comment: Thanks again Ron. Deleted that line as well in the final code!

Answer (score 0):

Use Areas And copy them:

```
Row = 1
Col = 1
For Each R In Range("bufferFields").Areas
    R.Copy Destination:=Sheets("History").Cells(Row, Col)
    Row = Row + R.Rows.Count
Next
```

This will put all the values into one column.
If you want all the columns from the range next to eachother, use

```
    Col = Col + 1 ' instead of Row = Row + R.Rows.Count
```

If you really want ONE ROW with all the values, like in your code, use (warning: this code uses copy-pasting that may interfere with the user):

```
Row = 1
Col = 1
For Each R In Range("bufferFields").Areas
    R.Copy
    Sheets("History").Cells(Row, Col).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    Col = Col + R.Rows.Count
Next
```

If there are a lot of formulas in your sheet, you speed the code up the most, by putting

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

before your code and

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

after your copying code. This may speed up VERY much if the workbook is large.

Comment: Roemer, it seems promising, but I didn't try/implement your method because I personally don't like to use copy/paste functions, as they interfere with the user's clipboard.

Comment: True. Just change the line Copy and paste lines to 
    R.Copy destination:=Worksheets("History").Cells(Row,Col)

Makes your code much simpeler. I'll edit it.
To prevent that. Also, biggest win is my last tip, but you already found that out.

Comment: The code now in my solution does NOT mess with the user's copy and paste. It is much more elegant than using arrays, but which is the wuickest, you should just test.